# Using node.js and graphql - I'm trying to display the total number of students for each school, but by Promise.all(), it returns empty

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

```
    async studentCount(@Parent() school: School): Promise<number> {
        let studentIds = []
        let cohortStudentIds = []

        // find all the programs for each school
        const programs = await this.programService.find({ schoolId: school.id })

        // find all the cohorts for each program
        programs.map(async program => {

//collect the student ids per cohort within array
          const cohortsWithStudents = await this.cohortService.getStudentsForCohortsByProgramId(program.id)
          // find all the students by looping through each cohort and save in cohortStudentIds[]
          cohortsWithStudents.map(async (cohort) => {
            await cohort.students.map(async (student) => { await cohortStudentIds.push(student.id) })

          });
//collect all the student id arrays into 1 big array
        studentIds = await [
            ...studentIds,
            ...cohortStudentIds
          ]

        })

        await Promise.all([programs, cohortStudentIds, studentIds])
            .then((values) => {
              console.log( values )
              return values
            });
            console.log('xxx')

        //  return the number of students per school
        return uniq(studentIds).length
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an `async` function as the callback to `map()`, which results in an array of promises, but you're never waiting for *those*.

In contrast, you're `await`ing a lot of things you don't need to wait for as they are not promises, like the return value of `push`, the return value of `map`, or the array literal.

You should write something like

```
async studentCount(@Parent() school: School): Promise<number> {
    let studentIds = new Set

    const programs = await this.programService.find({ schoolId: school.id })

    await Promise.all(programs.map(async program => {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        const cohortsWithStudents = await this.cohortService.getStudentsForCohortsByProgramId(program.id)
        for (const cohort of cohortsWithStudents) {
            for (const student of cohort.students) {
                studentIds.add(student.id)
            }
        }
    });

    return studentIds.size
}
```